# Powershell out put results in a table

Tags: powershell

I am copying files from a source to multiple locations and then do a check against source to see if files are copied successfully. `$result` will list the results in console line by line, but when I trying to send `$result` to email, it ends up with everything in one line. I tried `format-table` and `converto-htl` without success. I would like to use `hashtable` but need some guidance.

```
    $Source = "C:\temp\Copy\00_S"
    $DST = "C:\temp\Copy\01_D","C:\temp\Copy\02_D","C:\temp\Copy\03_D"
    $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source\*.xml | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    $DST | %{Copy-Item $Source\*.xml -Destination $_ -Force}
    $result = Foreach ($item in $FileList){
       $DST | % {if (Test-Path ($_ + "\" +  "$item")){
            "$item exists in $_"
            }else{
            "$item does not exist in $_"
            }
           }
       }

     $result
```

Here is what I want to have in final look.

[image]

Comment: I think what you're trying to do would be very easily handled by 'rsync'   It's a *NIX tool, but according to this you can get it for Windoze:    https://github.com/backuppc/backuppc/wiki/How-to-make-Backup-using-Rsync-server-on-Windows    It will allow you to easily keep files in sync, copy updates when files are change, can even move files and delete the original ones when the copy completes if you want..  it's extremely flexible when you need to keep a group of files in sync, even on far away remote systems.

Comment: I am tasked to do this way, beside, files in source will be deleted after report generated, so can't be synced all the time with multiple locations.

Comment: Agreed, I don't see the point in reinventing the wheel. Use `robocopy`.

Comment: Sometimes the taskmaster is wrong.  rsync has been in use for decades, and it works.  It will tell you when a copy has succeeded, if things are up to date, which are newer/older...  it's incredibly flexible.   Good luck.

Comment: `robocopy` would be a good solution. Besides, it already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

```
# Initialise array
$results = @()

# Create a hashtable with the attributes you want to track
$result = @{
    Source = "File 1"
    Dest1  = "Yes"
    Dest2  = "Yes"
    Dest3  = "Yes"
}
# Append hashtable to results array
$results += $result

# Rinse-repeat
$result = @{
    Source = "File 2"
    Dest1  = "Yes"
    Dest2  = "Yes"
    Dest3  = "Yes"
}
$results += $result

$result = @{
    Source = "File 3"
    Dest1  = "Yes"
    Dest2  = "Yes"
    Dest3  = "Yes"
}
$results += $result

# Display the results
#  selecting the columns in your desired display order
#  and then converting to a HTML table
$results | Select-Object Source, Dest1, Dest2, Dest3 | ConvertTo-Html
```

Obviously you just need to bung this in to your existing loop... but I'll leave that in your capable hands `:-)`

## Results

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/
xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Source</th><th>Dest1</th><th>Dest2</th><th>Dest3</th></tr>
<tr><td>File 1</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>File 2</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>File 3</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

*-Fragment*

```
$results | Select-Object Source, Dest1, Dest2, Dest3 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Source</th><th>Dest1</th><th>Dest2</th><th>Dest3</th></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Isn't PowerShell awesome?!

Comment: I was trying your code, but I only got an empty table, no data filled into the table? any idea why?

Comment: @RootLoop try the following 3 lumps of code: `$results`, `$results | Select-Object Source, Dest1, Dest2, Dest3`, `$results | Select-Object Source, Dest1, Dest2, Dest3 | ConvertTo-Html`